# Problem targeting two separate links with togglebutton function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to have two separate links for two vertical slide-out nav bars be set off from a javascript function separately after clickon.

I've tried using the same togglebutton function with two classes which correspond to the two slide-out nav bars to no avail.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $toggleButton = $('.toggle-button-work'),
        $menuWrap = $('.menu-wrap-work'),
        $toggleButton = $('.toggle-button-about'),
        $menuWrap = $('.menu-wrap-about');    

    // Slide-out Nav - LEFT - MY WORK

    $toggleButton.on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('button-open-work');
        $menuWrap.toggleClass('menu-show');
    });     

    // Slide-out Nav - RIGHT - ABOUT

    $toggleButton.on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('button-open-about');
        $menuWrap.toggleClass('menu-about');
    });

});
```

I expect that since I'm using separate classes for each togglebutton it should work. However, it's only setting off one of the links or the right side slide-out nav link.

Comment: Is it a mobile application?

Answer (score 0):

why you are reassigning element selection?

```
var $toggleButton = $('.toggle-button-work'),
$menuWrap = $('.menu-wrap-work'),
$toggleButton = $('.toggle-button-about'),
$menuWrap = $('.menu-wrap-about');
```

you should assign to on diferent variables each element